# % after message suggestions in eclipse or sts

Tags: java, eclipse

After using the latest version of STS IDE I've noticed a percentage sign after the method suggestions pops-up. I have attached a screenshot here to clarify what I mean, hope someone can elaborate on this.

[image: Screenshot from STS]

Answer (score 1):

It represents how likely the IDE think it is that you would want to call that method based on what other developers in a similar situation have called on an object of that type.